# Negative magnitudes in the design of bandpass filter using Yulewalk in Matlab

Tags: matlab, filter

I am trying to implement the filter attached in the picture but I cannot get the correct result (as seen in the other picture) as the Yulewalk function does not accept negative magnitudes. Can someone please help me?

This is what I get:

[image]

This is what I want to get:

[image]

Comment: How do you get a negative magnitude, is that not just a positive magnitude with phase -180 degrees? I think that `yulewalk` requires a linear magnitude scale.

Comment: can you provide the definition of the function, something to the original docs, how you are calling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're getting mixed up between magnitude (which is a positive number by definition) and dB magnitude (which is a log ratio, and can be positive or negative). `yulewalk` works with just plain magnitude, so you'll need to convert your dB values to absolute magnitude. Use 0 dB = 1.0, -20 dB = 0.1, etc:

```
magnitude = 10 ^ (magnitude_dB / 20)
```